# How can I select until I find an "Error" string into dynamic log? regex

Tags: regex

I want to select dynamically from a log file all the text before "Summary" until I found Errors.
In this moment a succeeded to take only this string:

```
(Total Scanned Files = 0)(Start Time = 2/16/2021 8:42:55 AM)(End Time = 2/16/2021 8:43:24 AM)(Total Time = 0h 0m 29s)}
```

But T want to take the last "Summary" where I have and I find "Errors"
So my final selected string I want to be like this:

```
(Command ScanPath = \\D-022-an-lab\sdms\Data)(Total Scanned Files = 0)(Total Archived Files = 20)(Total Bytes = 2707931)(Start Time = 2/16/2021 8:43:24 AM)(End Time = 2/16/2021 8:44:20 AM)(Total Time = 0h 0m 55s)(Errors = 0)
```

My regex:

```
\bMessage[^\:]+:\s(?<LogEntryDate>[\d\-]+\s[\d\:]+):\s(?:Beginning|\<\-\sclsAAProxy)(?:[^{]+(?:{(?!Summary\s:\s(?=\(Total))[^{]+)+){Summary\s:\s(?:(?<Summary>(?<keyval>\((?<key>[^=]+)\s=\s(?<value>[^)]+)\))+)})(?>[^N]+(?:N(?!ext)[^N]+)*)\bNext\b\s[^\d]+(?<ReqNumber>\d+)\sis\s(?<NextRunDate>[\d\-]+\s[\d\:]+)
```

Also I put my log file into regex101: https://regex101.com/r/WwKLCx/1/

Comment: The regex demo at regex101.com you shared contains no `Total Bytes = 2702466` substring. Could you please update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
\bMessage[^:]+:\s(?<LogEntryDate>[\d-]+\s[\d:]+):\s(?:Beginning|<-\sclsAAProxy)[^{]*(?:{(?!Summary\s:\s\(Total[^{}]*\(Errors = \d+\)})[^{]*)*?{Summary\s:\s(?=[^{}]*\(Errors = \d+\)})(?:(?<Summary>(?<keyval>\((?<key>[^=]+)\s=\s(?<value>[^)]+)\))+)})[^N]+(?:N(?!ext)[^N]+)*\bNext\b\s\D*(?<ReqNumber>\d+)\s+is\s+(?<NextRunDate>[\d-]+\s[\d:]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SFJd70/2/)

I added `[^{}]*\(Errors = \d+\)})` in the negative lookahead to get exactly to the `{Summary` that contains the "Errors", and added `(?=[^{}]*\(Errors = \d+\)})` in the subsequent pattern part to make sure the captured `Summary` actually contains this substring.

Comment: it is possible to put Errors optional? if doesn't exists to get the first solution?

Comment: @Vladut I will check a bit later.This might make the pattern even more unreadable though.

Comment: please if you have time to follow this regex: https://regex101.com/r/cKg8Ij/1 , in the first paragraph you had a summary with "Errors" string  and the regex working grate but for the second paragraph we didn't have that "Errors" string into the summary and we want to keep the first version of regex. I try to combine this two, your good variant with mine, but with no luck. Thanks

Comment: Ok, glad it is finally [sorted out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69080274/3832970). I just did not have time yesterday.

Comment: It's perfect Wiktor Stribiżew, thanks a lot. Thanks for helping.