# How can I select the last paragraph "Summary" dynamically from a log file?

Tags: regex

I want to select all the details from the last "Summary" into a paragraph from a log file.
For my current regex I select the first "Summary" group of details.
You can see my example here: https://regex101.com/r/U8kTa1/1

```
\bMessage[^\:]+:\s(?<LogEntryDate>[\d\-]+\s[\d\:]+):\s(?:Beginning|\<\-\sclsAAProxy)(?:[^{]+(?:{(?!Summary\s:\s(?=\(Total))[^{]+)+)*?{Summary\s:\s(?:(?<Summary>(?<keyval>\((?<key>[^=]+)\s=\s(?<value>[^)]+)\))+)})(?>[^N]+(?:N(?!ext)[^N]+)*)\bNext\b\s[^\d]+(?<ReqNumber>\d+)\sis\s(?<NextRunDate>[\d\-]+\s[\d\:]+)
```

In this moment from my log I succeeded to select this part:

```
(Total Scanned Files = 0)(Start Time = 9/6/2021 12:16:12 PM)(End Time = 9/6/2021 12:16:12 PM)(Total Time = 0h 0m 0s)
```

But what I need is to select the last "Summary" with 8 tags details (instead of 4):

```
(Command ScanPath = c:\testdata\STD_1\)(Total Scanned Files = 0)(Total Archived Files = 12)(Total Bytes = 819816)(Start Time = 9/6/2021 12:16:12 PM)(End Time = 9/6/2021 12:16:12 PM)(Total Time = 0h 0m 0s)(Errors = 0)
```

If it helps I can selected until I find "Errors" string, but sometimes the paragraph doesn't have that word "Errors". In my log file I have 3 groups of paragraph, I want to select in each paragraph as you see into my regex the last "Summary".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pattern, you are using a tempered greedy token `{(?!Summary\s:\s` to not cross matching the first occurrence of Summary, and then start matching all the groups after matching that first occurrence.

That will only work for the 2nd part, as there is only 1 occurrence of Summary.

You might update the pattern to use `[\s\S]*?` to match any character non greedy.

You want to match the line with the next scheduled runtime using `(?>[^N]+(?:N(?!ext)[^N]+)*)\bNext` and and capture the time from that line

What you could do instead is match that line at the end of the pattern with a more precise match using `\r?\nMessage[^:]+:\s[\d-]+\s[\d:]+:\sNext\b\s[^\d]+(?<ReqNumber>\d+)\sis\s(?<NextRunDate>[\d-]+\s[\d:]+)`

**Note** that repeating capture groups like this `(?<keyval>\((?<key>[^=]+)\s=\s(?<value>[^)]+)\))+` will get the group key and value for the last iteration.

The updated pattern could look like:

```
\bMessage[^:]+:\s(?<LogEntryDate>[\d-]+\s[\d:]+):\s(?:Beginning|<-\sclsAAProxy)[\s\S]*?{Summary : (?<Summary>(?<keyval>\((?<key>[^=]+)\s=\s(?<value>[^)]+)\))+)}\.\r?\nMessage[^:]+:\s[\d-]+\s[\d:]+:\sNext\b\s[^\d]+(?<ReqNumber>\d+)\sis\s(?<NextRunDate>[\d\-]+\s[\d\:]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y8cso3/1)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help: (?<={Summary : ).*(?=}.\nMessage.*Next scheduled)

My exam: https://regex101.com/r/1foOsh/1

Comment: Thanks Thai Do, the example helping me to understand in more details.